# Apache Spark | java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed

Tags: apache-spark-2.0

I am using Apache Spark 2.0.2 and facing following issue while using cartesian product in Spark Streaming module.

I am using compression codec as snappy but facing the same issue while using the default one (LZ4), also using kryo for serialization.

I also see ample memory available in the executor section. Also, this exception happens while subsequent batches are run. 1st batch runs fine.

Please find the stack trace below:-

```
java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:156)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.forceSpill(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:195)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Spillable.spill(Spillable.scala:111)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.TaskMemoryManager.acquireExecutionMemory(TaskMemoryManager.java:150)
    at org.apache.spark.memory.MemoryConsumer.acquireMemory(MemoryConsumer.java:147)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.Spillable.maybeSpill(Spillable.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:160)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:332)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:951)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionerAwareUnionRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionerAwareUnionRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:154)
    at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineValuesByKey(Aggregator.scala:41)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$combineByKeyWithClassTag$1$$anonfun$apply$11.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:94)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitions$1$$anonfun$apply$23.apply(RDD.scala:785)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionerAwareUnionRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PartitionerAwareUnionRDD$$anonfun$compute$1.apply(PartitionerAwareUnionRDD.scala:99)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:434)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:440)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:439)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:461)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:79)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: have the same issue, did your find the reason?